# Calculate a new column in pandas with transform based on a subset of the group

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a set of categories and event dates. For each record, I would like to assign the previous date for that record's category.

This assigns the simple maximum for each group:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2013-02', '2013-03', freq='D').values[0:10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo',
                            'bar','bar','bar','bar','bar']
                   })
df['date'] = dates

df['latest'] = df.groupby(['category'])['date'].transform(max)
```

What I need is the maximum within the record's group that's less than than the record's date.

I can do this easily in SQL or ddply, but I haven't found a way to further subset a group in pandas.

Thanks.

EDIT: per the comment, my desired output would look like this:

```
category    date                previous
foo         2013-02-26          NA
foo         2013-02-27          2013-02-26
foo         2013-02-28          2013-02-27
foo         2013-03-01          2013-02-28
foo         2013-03-02          2013-03-01
bar         2013-03-03          NA
bar         2013-03-04          2013-03-03
bar         2013-03-05          2013-03-04
bar         2013-03-06          2013-03-05
```

etc

Comment: could you provide what output you expect to get with the above data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a long way around, but here's what I came up with:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2013-02', '2013-03', freq='D')
# create random index
rindex =  np.array(sample(xrange(len(dates)), 10))
# get 10 random dates
dates = dates[rindex]

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo',
                            'bar','bar','bar','bar','bar']
                   })
df['date'] = dates
df = df.set_index(['category', 'date'], drop=False)
df = df.sortlevel()
df['dateseq'] = df.groupby('category').date.rank().astype(int) - 1
df
# Increment each rank number by one to get the rank number of the next date
# in the group. Final-day records will get numbers that don't join, which is 
# what we want.
prevdates = df['dateseq']
prevdates = prevdates + 1

# convert the index back into columns
prevdates = prevdates.reset_index()
prevdates['prev_date'] = prevdates['date']
prevdates = prevdates.drop('date',1)
prevdates
# Use merge to join the two tables, with the category and sequence number for keys.
df = pd.merge(df, prevdates, how='left', left_on=['category','dateseq'], right_on=['category','dateseq'],
      left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
       copy=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an `expanding_max` function:

```
In [26]: df['latest'] = df.groupby(['category'])['date'].apply(pd.expanding_max)

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
  category       date        latest
0      foo 2013-02-27  1.361923e+18
1      foo 2013-02-28  1.362010e+18
2      foo 2013-03-01  1.362096e+18
3      foo 2013-03-02  1.362182e+18
4      foo 2013-03-03  1.362269e+18
5      bar 2013-03-04  1.362355e+18
6      bar 2013-03-05  1.362442e+18
7      bar 2013-03-06  1.362528e+18
8      bar 2013-03-07  1.362614e+18
9      bar 2013-03-08  1.362701e+18

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

And recast as datetime:

In [29]: df['latest'] = pd.to_datetime(df['latest'])

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
  category       date     latest
0      foo 2013-02-27 2013-02-27
1      foo 2013-02-28 2013-02-28
2      foo 2013-03-01 2013-03-01
3      foo 2013-03-02 2013-03-02
4      foo 2013-03-03 2013-03-03
5      bar 2013-03-04 2013-03-04
6      bar 2013-03-05 2013-03-05
7      bar 2013-03-06 2013-03-06
8      bar 2013-03-07 2013-03-07
9      bar 2013-03-08 2013-03-08

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

This give the maximum where the date is less than or equal to the record's date.

Comment: This is on the right track, but I need to know the maximum value that's less than the row's `date`. I have looked at the documentation for `expanding_max`, and I don't see how to get it with that. Thanks.